# Shva na after dalet prefix

Tags: grammar-dikduk, prayer-book, pronunciation

I noticed that in a few siddurim, in [Akdamut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akdamut) (line 30), the shva in סִיּוּמָא דִלְעָלַם is marked as a shva na (vocal shva). And I saw in a single siddur (Artscroll) that in Uva letzion, the shva under the מ in דִּמְשַׁבְּחִין is marked as a shva na.

It appear that these siddurim are trying to follow some rule for a shva after the Aramaic dalet prefix (meaning "that"). I could not find other examples of a dalet prefix followed by a shva in the siddur. And there are no examples in Biblical Aramaic, since afaik in the Bible the dalet prefix is never used (rather, the complete word דִּי is always used for "that").

What rule are these siddurim using? (Any answer would be appreciated, even if to point out that they are following a certain rule incorrectly.)